# Captura de datos por formulario

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress

Buen día comunidad tengo un problema, actualmente tengo un script que captura tanto los datos UTM y datos del formulario, los convierte en un Json y los envía un webhook. Mi problema es que actualmente solo hay 3 campos y futuramente habrán aterrizado con 4 o 5 campos de formulario y lo ideal es que los datos se capturen automáticamente sin modificar nada del código nuevamente.

Espero me puedan ayudar

```
// Capturar datos de formulario y setear el JSON
                function capturar_form(){
                var cookie_ref = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)__gtm_campaign_url\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1"));
                var cookie_url = cookie_ref.substring(cookie_ref.indexOf("?")+1);
                var cookie_ref_1 = cookie_url;
                var output = {};
                cookie_url.split(/\s*&\s*/).forEach(function(pair) {
                pair = pair.split(/\s*=\s*/);
                output[pair[0]] = pair.splice(1).join("=");
                  });
                var json = output;
                    var nombre = document.getElementById("et_pb_contact_nombre_0").value;
                    var mail=document.getElementById("et_pb_contact_correo_0").value;
                    var phone=document.getElementById("et_pb_contact_celular_0").value;

      //Capturar url de completo con path
      var URLactual_origin = window.location.origin;
      var urlactual_path = window.location.pathname;
      var url_final = URLactual_origin+urlactual_path;
      // console.log(URLactual_origin + urlactual_path);

                    var json_var = {};
                    json_var.nombre = nombre;
                    json_var.email = mail;
                    json_var.telefono = phone;

      var json_url={};
      json_url.secondary_content=url_final;

      var obj_unidos = JSON.stringify(Object.assign(json_url, json, json_var));

    //Envio de la informacion a Make
    //validar mail
    var regex = /^\w+([\.\+\-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/;
    var email_validate = document.getElementById("et_pb_contact_correo_0").value;

if (regex.test(email_validate)) {
      var myHeaders = new Headers();
      myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

      var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: obj_unidos,
        redirect: 'follow'
      };

      fetch("https://hook.us1.make.com/we83rcy0fa4cvbuojd6nnn3ox37sevc1", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  } else {
      console.log("La dirección de email es incorrecta.");
  }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una especie de serialización, paracido a lo que tenía jQuery, con [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FormData), de esta manera tomas el form completo y buscas los inputs, luego los guardas en un objeto.

```js
let form = document.querySelector('form');
let formData = new FormData(form);
let object = {};
formData.forEach((value, key) => {
 object[key] = isNaN(Number(value)) ? value : Number(value); //Esto para respetar si es número o no
//object[key] = value; Si solo guardas texto, ocupar esta forma
});
console.info(object);
```

```html
<form>
<input name="a" value="1" />
<input name="b" value="2" />
<input name="c" value="3" />
<input name="d" value="Casa" />
</form>
```

Comment: Genial muchas gracias por la respuesta, con jQuery puedo hacer que un botón del form llame al primer formulario que este arriba? es decir si tengo 3 formularios en una landing se puede hacer que tome los datos del primer form que este arriba del boton submit?